# In App Purchases with multiple products

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am setting up a subscription app, and I want to have 2 options: 2 months, and 1 year.  Here is the code I'm currently using that works for the 2 month purchase.  How do I modify it to have both?

```
func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
    let products = response.products
    if products.count != 0 {
        product = products[0] as! SKProduct
    }
}



func getProductInfo() {
        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            let productID : NSSet = NSSet(object: "2MonthPrem")
            let request : SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
    }
}
```

The problem occurs with the second function : getProductInfo().  How do I add a second product ID?  I tried the following:

```
        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            let productID : NSSet = NSSet(object: "2MonthPrem")
            let productIDTwo : NSSet = NSSet(object: "1YearPrem")
            let request : SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: [productID, productIDTwo] as Set<NSObject>)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mason, I just wanted to explain the reason I removed "in SWIFT" from the title. Since you've chosen the Swift tag there's no benefit to it being in the title, it's just added noise. Having it in the title doesn't make your post more visible to Swift users, they're searching by tag, and in google web results your posts will say "Swift - In App Purchases with multiple products". Just an fyi

Comment: have you tried `let productID : NSSet = NSSet(array: ["2MonthPrem", "1YearPrem"])`?

Comment: Sega-zero.  That worked.  I have one question for you.  Doing that, when I pull them out of the array in the productsRequest function, the "1YearPrem" is index 0, and "2MonthPrem" is index 1.  Does Apple alphabetize them?  I also tried out switching their order in getProductInfo() and they came out "1Year: index 0, 2 month, index 1.  I'm guessing alphabetized, but hoping you can confirm?

Comment: You should not rely on the order of elements. Use symbolic names always to prevent any mistakes, since this affects your users money.

Answer (score 0):

```
let productID : NSSet = NSSet(array: ["2MonthPrem", "1YearPrem"])
```

this works, but when you call it back from Apple it will alphabetize them.  So make sure you test each array Index in the return function.